# How to actually deploy to a serious host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, meteor, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It's so undescribably discouraging and frustrating that deploying is such a pain. There are no step-by-step guides and every information source is outdated. I have NO idea where to begin!

I want to deploy Meteor apps to AWS (EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk) but now I've learned that it doesn't support Websockets or sticky sessions. I don't know what the latter means, but the former sounds like a big deal breaker. How can the biggest host on the Internet not support something so fundamental?

Should I just not use AWS at all? It's pretty much the only scalable host on the Internet, so that's discouraging in itself. I've read about Load Balancing and understand exactly 0 % of it, and I broke out in a sweat just typing that word here just now.

So, first of all: is it true that AWS/Elastic Beanstalk doesn't support websockets?

Second: What other issues should I look out for when deploying?

Comment: Be careful. Your wording seem to imply you want advices, not hard facts ("serious host", "no idea where to begin" (that's one of the best catch phrase for off-topic flags), "how can it be so bad", "should I", "I don't understand that", "I don't know where to begin", and worst of all: "where do I go"). I can understand your frustration, but please keep it nice and professional. As I see it, you lack a lot of crucial data  and knowledge (load balancing is uberly important to begin with). The MDG is aware of the state of deployment: they're [making their own, galaxy!](https://roadmap.meteor.com/)

Comment: Man, you seem really confused. I have two recommendations for you. First: check your sources. You can for sure have web sockets on EC2. Second: if you understand 0% of load balancers, you are not ready to develop something that needs a "serious host". Good luck

Comment: @MatteoSp So I need to get experience before I can... get experience?

Comment: Never hear about studying?

Comment: @MatteoSp That's the problem. There is literally zero information on the subject.

Comment: @Kyll Thank you, Kyll, I know. I'm extremely frustrated and don't know where to turn. :(

Comment: modulus wasn't hard to deploy to, I'd say that's pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up). Its README has some thorough documentation, and its primary hosting destination is AWS. And yes, AWS supports Websockets. Just follow the Meteor Up instructions.

Comment: Why do people say it doesn't then?

Comment: You’re clearly speaking to the wrong people. It might be time to find a new crowd.

Comment: Well, it's just from googling. This Youtube comment for example: " yep, I got it working to then find out that AWS don't support (or at least at that point of time) Websockets and sticky sessions. So I jumped to AWS Opsworks... and low and behol their out of the box NGINX does support it but not with HTTPS, so you have to create your own NGINX layer. Arrrrgghh... Yesterday, I logged another AWS support call to check if there are any imminent plans to support out of the box on either ELB or Opsworks.... so close but yet so far ;-)"

Comment: Does Elastic Beanstalk also support it? Are there other issues to look out for?

Comment: I have a Meteor app in production on AWS, with HTTPS, and websockets work. I didn’t need to do anything special, it’s just an Ubuntu instance. I’m using EC2, I don’t know about Beanstalk.

Comment: All right, thanks! As I understand it EC2 is for "pros" and takes days to setup, while EB is more newbie-friendly, right?

Comment: That hasn’t been my experience. Meteor Up automates the entire process, there isn’t really any custom configuring to do. Just follow the instructions and screencast.

Comment: The screencast at the top of the Meteor Up instructions. That’s specific to Digital Ocean, but here’s [one for AWS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11K_DSrhJzQ).